# XCTest - StaticText elements returning in incorrect order

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, ios-ui-automation

Writing an XCUITest case using Swift, XCTest, and XCode 9.1.  The application is displaying correct but when we pull back the staticText that is getting displayed, it is getting returned in the wrong order.

We put a debug break point in and it displays the following when we run XCUIApplication():

[image]

Yet, when looking at the application it is displaying:

[image]

It is switching the "Instructions" and the "Switch.." lines so our expect statements are failing.

We pull the staticText from the screen by:

```
func tableRowsText(tableRows: XCUIElementQuery) -> [String] {
   let endRow = tableRows.staticTexts.count
   var rowsText = [String]()

   for i in 0 ..< endRow {
       let textElement = tableRows.staticTexts.element(boundBy: i)
       rowsText.append(textElement.label)
   }

   return rowsText
```

}

It has the correct number of rows/endRow and loops through all but the last two that are displayed get flipped.

It seems as though it has something to do with the elements not being displayed on some of the smaller simulators.

Comment: UI tests are not intended to verify layout requirements (they are for testing functional requirements), therefore the order in which elements are presented cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: Are the elements read in the correct order by VoiceOver? If not, you could try setting the view's `accessibilityElements` array to order the elements appropriately.